systemd user service: ExecStartPost not running, service stuck in 'activating' state
I have a systemd user service file ~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service, the purpose of which is to ensure that I always have my ssh-agent running, and a particular passphrase-less SSH key loaded into it. It currently looks like this:
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/ssh-add $MYSSH

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

After my system starts up, I check that the ssh-agent has started with ps -aux | grep "ssh", which returns this:
myuser       535  0.0  0.0   8008  5104 ?        Ss   15:22   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket

However, when I check that the key has been added as I expect with ssh-add -l, I get back The agent has no identities.
Now, I can verify that /usr/bin/ssh-add $MYSSH executed manually does what I like, so that would seem not to be the issue. So, I check the service status with systemctl --user status ssh-agent.service and receive the following:
● ssh-agent.service - SSH key agent
     Loaded: loaded (/home/myUser/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2024-09-17 15:22:27 EDT; 1h 18min ago
 Invocation: 6509facc63a8488780f5674e11c865f6
   Main PID: 535 (ssh-agent)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8976)
     Memory: 1.1M (peak: 1.5M)
        CPU: 6ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/ssh-agent.service
             └─535 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket

Sep 17 15:22:27 mySystem systemd[525]: Starting SSH key agent...
Sep 17 15:22:27 mySystem ssh-agent[535]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
Sep 17 15:22:27 mySystem ssh-agent[535]: echo Agent pid 535;

I notice that the ssh-add command is not mentioned here, and that the service just hangs in the activating state, even though the agent is up and running.
It seems like the ExecStartPost statement is never firing. I tested that it wasn't something in the statement itself by changing that line to
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/echo Hello, world.

and restarting. Echo never executed, and the response from systemctl --user status ssh-agent.service was the same as before.

The service unit starts a daemon, so it should not be Type=oneshot. That type is specifically for processes that perform a short task and exit, so naturally the service startup is waiting for the ssh-agent process to exit.
Because you've used the -D option to make ssh-agent "not fork", it will of course never exit (until manually stopped). The best match for this is Type=exec (or the very similar but very slightly worse Type=single).
In the default mode that ssh-agent operates (i.e. without the -D option), you'd want Type=forking, which waits for the initial process to fork a child and then exit; the service would then track the child process and promote it to MainPID.
(The latter is what makes Type=forking different from Type=oneshot. If you attempted to remove -D while keeping Type=oneshot, the service would be considered stopped as soon as the parent process forked and exit, and the child process would quickly get killed as "leftover".)
With well-written daemons, Type=forking (i.e. without -D) is generally a slightly better choice than Type=exec as it allows any errors caught before forking to propagate as service start errors.
